# Is the Borg Sphere in Voy: Drone the same as the ones seen in Voy: Dark Frontier or First Contact?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

In the episode "Drone", the sphere that was on the way to intercept them was described as a:

> long range tactical vessel with ablative hull armor.

Is this Borg Sphere identical to the Sphere described as a "*scout ship*" in VOY: Dark Frontier, Part I or the one in First Contact?

Comment: Yeah, the person  who edited that should  explain that to me sometime, would be very funny

Comment: @Richard actually drone is a voyager episode

Comment: It's easy to get mixed up with the two

Comment: It would appear that the studio model for the spheres seen in both Voyager and the First Contact film were identical; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_sphere_model

Comment: I got mixed up. {shrugs}

Comment: Memory Alpha wiki identifies them as a single class of vessel; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_sphere

Comment: I think there is a difference like a Borg cube and Borg tactical cube , there is a tactical sphere also

Comment: There's some interesting concept art [here](http://fsd.trekships.org/art/borg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/borg_ships.htm/), the Borg have multiple classes and types of ships that are used. In addition to the Borg Cube, they also have armored "Tactical Cubes," lighter scout ships, spherical ships, and different stations. Largely, each ship class is used for a specific need (such as speed or firepower) that can be better filled by a more specialized ship than a more general one.

Comment: This question was about spheres from the start someone made a mistake editing my question

Comment: Good answer, but alas the question was edited and this no longer makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, I got this in after the bad edit but before it was corrected. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, and no.

Borg Spheres seem to come in two sizes; big (AKA "*Tactical*") at around 1500m-ish and small (AKA "*scout/lifeboat*") at around 450m-ish. The Borg Sphere seen in 'Drone' appears to be a *variant* of those seen in First Contact film and although the models used (both physical and digital) were [identical](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_sphere_model), the notable difference is that the spheres in Drone are [dramatically larger](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/schematics/borg_ships.htm), at what appears to be around three times the size.

The Sphere seen in Unimatrix Zero, Part I seems to be the larger variant and the sphere seen in Endgame seems to be the smaller kind.

So yes, out of universe they're totally the same. In-universe, they're not.

Answer (score 0):

Probably. The Borg Collective has essentially two ships, the sphere scout spaceship and the giant cube one. The sphere has 160 decks, a crew of 11,000 drones.

Here is a comparison with USS Voyager: [USS Voyager NCC-74656 size compared to Borg Sphere](https://w3ask.com/uss-voyager-ncc-74656-size-compared-borg-sphere/).

Comment: What does the comparison with Voyager have to do with the question here?